# Generic Paths with AWS API Gateway

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

Let's say I have a RESTful web service with the following API:

```
/
  /things
    /v2
      /heartbeat
        GET
      /stuff
        GET
        POST
        ...
```

This service is running in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk behind an AWS API Gateway.  The service itself handles routing beyond the `/things` path so I don't want to duplicate this routing logic in the API Gateway configuration.  Is there a way I can setup my AWS API Gateway to handle any request that is `/things` and pass that to my service where the service will then handle routing to the correct path and method?

In other words, my API Gateway would handle a request to `https://myUrl.com/things/v2/heartbeat` and another request to `https://myUrl.com/things/v2/stuff` using the same `/things` resource defined in my API Gateway rather than having to define the `/heartbeat` and `/stuff` resources in the API Gateway itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use API Gateway's catch-all path variable to do that.

In your case, you'd have an method of type ANY, with the path `/things/{proxy+}`

The `Endpoint URL` you'd use would be something like: https://api.yourbackend.com/{proxy}

Here is a screenshot showing an example HTTP proxy integration in the API Gateway console:
[image: API Gateway example HTTP proxy integration]

This blog post has more details and screen shots:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/